# Convert column/variable to row names for multiple lists in R with sapply

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a column to row names for each list of an object using `sapply`.

`tibble::column_to_rownames()` is not an option because it ["always returns a data frame"](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html).

For a single variable (class `sf`, `data.frame`), using the `base` function:

```
rownames(polygon_nyc_listings[[1]]) <- polygon_nyc_listings[[1]]$zipcode
```

It works perfectly without changing the class: `sf`, `data.frame`.

So I am trying to repeat for each list the function above without success:

```
test <- sapply(polygon_nyc_listings,
                 function(x){rownames(x) <- x$zipcode},
                 simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

I instead get an object with zipcode lists class `character`.

Does someone know how to proceed?

Comment: you need to return the data.frame, otherwise it by default returns x$zipcode, do this function(x){rownames(x) <- x$zipcode; x}

Comment: You can easily convert the `data.frame` output from `column_to_rownames`  to `sf` using `st_to_sf` with likely no additional arguments (depending on your dataset).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in R functions return the last line or explicit `return()` call, your anonymous function `function(x) { rownames(x) <- x$zipcode }` returns the result of `row.names` which per [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html):

> `row.names` returns a character vector.

This can be quickly fixed by calling x after row names change as commented, `function(x) { rownames(x) <- x$zipcode; x }` or `function(x) { rownames(x) <- x$zipcode; return(x) }`.

However, consider [`row.names<-`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html) (subtle difference with assignment operator embedded):

```
function(x) { `rownames<-`(x, value= x$zipcode }
```

which per same [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html):

> `row.names<-` returns a data frame with the row names changed.

Altogether, removing redundant curly braces `{...}` and default `USE.NAMES = TRUE`:

```
test_list <- sapply(polygon_nyc_listings, 
                    function(df) `row.names<-`(df, value = df$zipcode),
                    simplify = FALSE)
```